# My toggle divs break on collapse all because of one active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this simple toggle divs:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/K5XC5/4/)

```
$(this).next().slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
```

Pretty simple...but the thing is I have the first one be opened on page load like this:

```
$('.container h3:first-child').trigger('click');
```

But here lies my issue when I collapse I want it to open or close, but it messes up with the first one..obviously my first child trigger is effecting....Even if I open the second one and collapse sometimes the third breaks too...

....how do i have both functions work together?

Comment: why not use [an accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)? Especially as you are using jQuery ui anyway - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/K5XC5/6/

Comment: Good question, the problem is I was taking over this code thats content driven...that might be the way though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an extra `if` statement you should be able to achieve the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container h3").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow", function () {});
        $("#collapse").removeClass("collapsed");
    });
    $('.container h3:first-child').trigger('click');

    $("#collapse").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
            $(".container h3").addClass("active").next().slideDown("fast");
        } else {
            $(".container h3").removeClass("active").next().slideUp("fast");

        }
        $(this).toggleClass("collapsed");
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K5XC5/7/)

Edit: Updated the answer with an extra `if` statement. I believe this does what you try to achieve. If not, please collaborate.

Comment: Nice but it still breaks. When you click on the third one and collapse after...the third one hides.

Comment: @Riskbreaker I've updated the answer and Fiddle. I believe it now does what you want. If not, please explain what it exactly is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Awesome your active calls makes sense. Thanks!